# Filtering Certutil.exe output for non-autoenrolling certificates

Tags: powershell, filter, windows-server-2008-r2, ca

I'm using [a script by Tom Nolan](http://www.tinyint.com/index.php/2010/08/09/ca-certificate-expiration-monitoring/) to query our CA for expiring certificates. However, I tried to no avail to filter the output for non-autoenrolling certificates, as these are the only ones of interest. That's the line in question:

```
certutil -view -restrict "NotAfter>=$d1,NotAfter<=$d2" -out "Request ID, Request Submission Date, Request Common Name, Requester Name, Request Email Address, Request Distinguished Name, CertificateTemplate, NotAfter" -config "$caServer\$caName"
```

I tried narrowing down the -restrict parameter like this:

```
-restrict "NotAfter>=$d1,NotAfter<=$d2,EnrollmentFlags&&0x20"
```

but had no success.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Certutil is quite picky on the datetime format, so that might cause some issues. Try and specify an explicit format, like so:

```
# $sd, $ed are datetimes
certutil -view -restrict "NotAfter>={0},NotAfter<={1}" -f $sd.toString("d.M.yyyy H:mm"), $ed.toString("d.M.yyyy H:mm")
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I could have been a bit more clear - $d1 and $d2 are calculated like this: $d1 = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString() ($d2 is just that plus the specified warning days).

Comment: So it isn't the dates that are worrying me, but the EnrollmentFlags.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one but still might help someone.

What you need to add is -restrict "enrollmentflags=0"

They are the ones that arent being auto-enrolled